# reledmac/reledpar: Use \color in \ledlsnotefontsetup and \ledrsnotefontsetup command

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I newly discovered the `reledmac`/`reledpar` packages and try to configure them according to my needs. Here's my (not exactly minimal) example.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}

% showframe --> To show the margins
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[]{reledmac} % usefull options widthliketwocolumns, series={}, noeledsec
% reledmac configuration
\renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily}% 
\renewcommand{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily}% 
\sidenotemargin{outer}

\usepackage[]{reledpar}
% reledpar configuration
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\section{Testsection A}]
                \blindtext

                \ledleftnote{Side note on the \textbf{left}}

                \blindtext
            \pend
            \pstart[\section{Testsection B}]
                \blindtext
            \pend            
         \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[\section{Testsection A}]
                \blindtext
            \pend
            \pstart[\section{Testsection B}]
                \blindtext

                \ledrightnote{Side note on the \textbf{right}}

                \blindtext                
            \pend           
         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

The commands  `\ledlsnotefontsetup` (left) and `\ledrsnotefontsetup` (right) help to set up the sidenotes which have the command `\ledleftnote` and `\ledrightnote`.

In my case I use

```
\renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily}
```

**Question:** I would like to **color** the text as well using the `\color` command from the `xcolor` package. But

```
\renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily\color{red}}
\renewcommand{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\scriptsize\sffamily\color{blue}}
```

have no effect.

Comment: that seems to be a bug, I will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug in reledmac. The version 2.9.0 of reledmac, which will be published on 2016/05/08 on CTAN will solve it. For now, you can download it on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/mac2.10.0-par2.9.0.zip.